# CAS implementation with JSON token

Tags: json, single-sign-on, cas, jwt

I created a cas flow with JWT tokens as :

1. user click siteX login ->  siteX redirects to CAS server login page with
   siteX URL.(http://cas.xx/url=siteA)
2. After user logins on CAS server, it response with   (TokenC + SiteX
   URL),then CAS page(in browser) saves it in CAS page localstorage.
3. CAS page requests(on button click) to CAS server with TokenC + (siteX Url)
4. CAS server checks token if  yes, then redirects the client with
   (SiteA url + TokenX)
5. SiteX server checks tokenX with CAS Server and authorizes the next
   step to client etc..

Is this kind of approach is secure/reliable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CAS can validate the token, according to the CAS document, SiteX should unpack the jwt and do the validation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).